# Creating own table widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I have looked at different solutions to similar questions and none of them seem to work with what I'm trying to do. I am trying to create a table that will display data in tkinter. Of course, because there isn't a table widget in tkinter, I'm trying to make one myself. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
    from tkinter import *
    
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("500x500")
    
    def clicked():
        print("clicked")

    canvas = Canvas(root, height=500, width=500, background="blue")
    canvas.pack()
      
    frame=Frame(root, background="red")
    
    def table(self, frame):
             
        for i in range(total_rows):
            for j in range(total_columns):
                     
                self.e = Entry(frame, width=20, fg='blue',
                               font=('Arial',16,'bold'))
                     
                self.e.grid(row=i, column=j)
                self.e.insert(END, lst[i][j])
    
    
    lst = [(1,'first','last',19),
           (2,'fname','lname',18),
           (3,'name','nameeee',20),
           (4,'tsrif','tsal',21),
           (5,'bobby','bobberson',21)]

    total_rows = len(lst)
    total_columns = len(lst[0])
    
    
    b=Button(canvas, text="test button", command=clicked)
    b.place(x=10, y=10)

    canvas.create_window(500, 500, window=frame)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

What I'm trying to have happen is to put a table in a frame and then place that frame in a canvas (as I will also be having other widgets placed in the canvas/window). I do not get any errors but it just doesn't turn up. What does display is the blue background and the test button. Is it because I haven't used pack and padx and pady? If so, how do I do that? Is it also because I have no idea how to call the function into the frame? I really appreciate any help

Comment: `table()` is not a class method, so why is there a `self` argument?

Comment: It did have a class method at some point during one of my tries, I just forgot to take it out before posting. Thank you for pointing it out I would've completely forgotten about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a few modifications to your code example.

I've used row & column configure to enable canvas to expand into window.

It's best to use grid manager through out.

I've created list 'enter' to store your `Entry` widgets for easy access.

Button must be destroyed after usage so create `Button` before function table.

Named canvas window so as to make changes (position|content) of your data table.

You still need to create a function to access `Entry` widgets in list 'enter'.

This code works on Windows 10, Python 3.9.1.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
# enable canvas to expand into root window
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

root.geometry('446x404+842+163')
canvas = Canvas(root, height=400, width=500, background="blue")

# use grid manager to make canvas resizable
canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

frame=Frame(root, background="red")

# Create list to access entry widgets as in 'enter[i][j].get() or set()'
enter = []

# Make button before table function
b=Button(canvas, text="test button")
b.place(x=10, y=10)

# No need to pass anything to table function
def table():

    b.destroy()

    for i in range(total_rows):

        enter.append([])

        for j in range(total_columns):

            enter[i].append(Entry(frame, width=15, fg='blue', font=('Arial',9,'bold')))

            enter[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j)
            enter[i][j].insert(END, lst[i][j])


lst = [(1,'first','last',19),
       (2,'fname','lname',18),
       (3,'name','nameeee',20),
       (4,'tsrif','tsal',21),
       (5,'bobby','bobberson',21)]

total_rows = len(lst)
total_columns = len(lst[0])
# Button accesses table directly
b["command"] = table
# name the canvas window (allows you to control window position and contents)
# Note the use of anchor 'nw'
window = canvas.create_window(5, 5, window=frame, anchor = "nw")

root.mainloop()
```